# Firefox ignoring content-type of AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, cors

I'm using jQuery to perform an AJAX multipart form upload. This is a CORS request.

```
// performs a multipart form upload
self.upload = function (path, formData) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: this.createUri(path),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, // otherwise jQuery will convert to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: configureRequest
    });
};
```

The server returns a JSON response with the headers set as below

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length      176
Content-Type        application/json; charset=utf-8
```

In Chrome/Safari the response content is returned as a JavaScript object. According to the jQuery docs:

> dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
>   If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME
>   type of the response

In Firefox the response content is returned as a `string` so it appears it is ignoring the `Content-Type` header. I can fix this by setting `dataType: "json"` but would like to understand whether this is caused by something I'm doing wrong or if it is an issue with Firefox.

An example JSON payload returned from the server:

```
[
    {
        "name": "5711b4bc4cdde896.png",
        "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/001/5711b4bc4cdde896.png",
        "relativePath": "5711b4bc4cdde896.png",
        "contentType": "image/png",
        "sizeInBytes": 299724,
        "lastUpdated": "2013-03-10T23:31:13Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try removing the charset part of the content type and see what happens.

Comment: On the one hand you say *"The server returns a JSON response with the headers set"*, but then go on to say *"In Firefox the response content is returned as a string"*. Are you saying the server sets a content-type of application/json, but then Firefox does not receive that header? What does firebug network tab show? Or fiddler? How is your server setting the content-type header? Is it explicit, or are you relying on content-type negotiation?

Comment: The firebug network tab shows the same as what I've posted - the content-type header is `application/json`. The *content* returned to the AJAX handler is a `string` in Firefox and an `Object` in other browsers. The server does perform conneg but returns JSON by default.

Comment: Try setting the `Accept` header, `Accept: application/json`.